# How can I perform a meta-analysis on Kendall's tau?

Tags: correlation, ranking, networks, kendall-tau, social-network

### Goal

Networks can have so many nodes that it's hard to study them.
That is why in some cases nodes are clustered together.
I am looking at whether the betweenness of a node similar to the one of its cluster.
In particular, at how its betweenness is ranked compared to the one of the other nodes.
In other words, does the ranking of the nodes change because of the clustering? I did as follows:

1. Calculate the betweenness centrality of the nodes.
2. Cluster similar nodes
3. Connect the clusters. This creates an "aggregated network".
4. Calculate the betweenness centrality of the clusters.
5. Set the "new betweenness centrality" of the nodes as the betweenness centrality of the cluster they belong to.

### Concerns about using Kendall's tau b

To compare the betweenness of the nodes with the one of their cluster, I was thinking to use Kendall's tau b. This was not a problem for a single network. However, when it comes to multiple networks with a different number of nodes, I wonder if comparing their Kendall's tau b coefficients makes sense. My questions are:

1. Would it be okay to compare different Kendall's tau b for different networks?
2. Does kendall's tau greatly rely on normality and monotonicity assumptions?
3. Is there any good source I could look into to better understand Kendall's tau? For example a book chapter. I have tried to read *Rank Correlation Methods* by Kendall, but it was too long and complicated to understand where the useful parts lied.

Cheers!